# document.elementFromPoint not working in jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, visibility

I'm trying to create a jQuery script to find if a required element is visible (not hidden from other elements) at given coordinates.

For this goal, I'm trying to use the `document.elementFromPoint` function but it seems it doesn't work (see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fbnkjmz0/1/)).

**JS**

```
var test = $("#test");
var debug = $("#debug");

// "test" is larger than 100x100 px, so I suppose to find it here
if(document.elementFromPoint(100,100) === test) {
    debug.html("found!");
}
else {
    debug.html("not found");
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: This is easy: you are comparing an instance of `jQuery` to an instance of `HTMLDivElement`. Either use Ionică Bizău's answer or drop jQuery and use `document.getElementById()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`elementFromPoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.elementFromPoint) returns the [`DOMElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element), so you need to get the DOM element instead of jQuery object:

```
if(document.elementFromPoint(100,100) === test[0]) {
    debug.html("found!");
}
else {
    debug.html("not found");
}
```

Another way is to use `is` jQuery method [this way](http://jsfiddle.net/fbnkjmz0/3/):

```
if(test.is(document.elementFromPoint(100,100))) {
   /* found */
}
else {
   /* not found */
}
```

> ### [`Document.elementFromPoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.elementFromPoint)
>
> Returns the element from the document whose elementFromPoint method is being called which is the topmost element which lies under the given point.  To get an element, specify the point via coordinates, in CSS pixels, relative to the upper-left-most point in the window or frame containing the document.
>
> ---
>
> ### [`.is( elements )`](http://api.jquery.com/is/#is-elements)
>
> Description: Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments.
>
> - elements
>
>   Type: `Element`
>
>   One or more elements to match the current set of elements against.

---

```js
var test = $("#test");
var debug = $("#debug");

if (document.elementFromPoint(100, 100) === test[0]) {
  debug.html("found!");
} else {
  debug.html("not found");
}
```

```css
#test {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
<p id="debug"></p>
```